# Permission Denied on file creation when running JBoss AS as a *nix service

Tags: java, linux, service, jboss, permissions

### Main Issue

I have successfully set up a JBoss staging server to be run as a linux service (Debian distribution and more specifically A Linux Mint 15).

When I run the service (not with root profile = no `sudo`):

```
~ $ service jboss start
```

everything works fine except for a module where I used to create a file to write in some report stuff and seems like the file creation is denied because of permission limitations.

My sources for the code where I create a new `File` are as follows:

```java
// My Report class constructor
public class Report

   private BufferedWriter writer;

   public Report() throws IOException
   {
      final File reportFile =
         new File("report-" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy-HH-mm").format(new Date()) + ".txt");

      AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>()
      {
         public Void run() throws IOException
         {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(reportFile)));
            return null;
         }
      });
   }
...
}
```

```java
public class ReportGenerator {
   ...
   public void createNewReport() {
      //Here is where the Report is created
      Report report = new Report();
      ...
   }
}
```

All the pain comes clearly from the fact that I'm starting the AS as *nix service but it seems weird to me as I have run through all instructions that I could make and below are small hints.

### What I tried to bypass this Security restriction

- I have set the *jboss-user* to be owner of the jboss service script:

  ```
  ~ $ sudo chown jboss-user:jboss-group /etc/init.d/jboss
  ```
- I have tried to run the service in a straightforward way:

  ```
  ~ $ service jboss start
  ```

  then tried to make sure that it is run with *jboss-user* as a user:

  ```
  ~ $ sudo -u jboss-user service jboss start
  ```
- After some debugging sessions, I realized that initially the `reportFile` was created under the **root folder** ("***/***"), so I managed to initialize the *user.dir* system property and set it up to a directory path (*/report*) under *jboss-user* home directory (to make sure the user have read/write permissions):

  ```
  JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Duser.dir="/home/jboss-user/report""
  ```

  The `ls -l /home/jboss-user` shows that all actions are permitted for all users under the *report* file:

  > drwxrwxrwx 9 jboss-user jboss-user    4096 juil. 21 10:16 report
- I have added a `SecurityManager` and declared a security policy file:

  ```
  JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/home/jboss-user/.java.policy"
  ```

  The */home/jboss-user/.java.policy* has below content, (all permissions are granted):

  ```
  grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
  };
  ```

  Also tried to explicitely add the file permissions

  ```
  grant codeBase "file:${jboss.home}/*" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}${/}*", "write, read";
  };
  grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
  };
  ```

After applying all above tricks, I still cannot have my file created and I still stack with a:

```
PrivilegedExceptionAction: Permission Denied
```

I have also tried to play with directory permissions, jboss service script owner, the java policy rules but none of these has made the line.

***One more addendum that I should point id that there is no issue when running the JBoss AS basically from the start script and I can have my file successfully created.***

Comment: Have you tried running your test case in the exact same environment, but with the SecurityManager disabled?

Comment: Yes but it already gives the same result... `Permission Denied`

Comment: What happens if you run your code without the SecurityManager, and unwrap the code inside the doPrivileged block? Do you still get the same problem then?

Comment: Haven't tried that so far, I will test it but I don't think it can be a final trick since I should keep the sources as is and manage to solve the situation without any codebase changes.

Comment: Agreed, but just debugging techniques. But reviewing your code more thoroughly, I would recommend you make your Report implement Runnable better yet, Callable, and put the logic you currently have in the constructor in the appropriate method. Best practices encourage minimal required code for object construction in constructors. Anything that is not required to create or initialize the object should not be in the constructor.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this approach was followed to ensure some backward compatibility with some third party staff which goes out of this issue scope thus no need to describe it. But I will plan enhancing the code as you suggested in future.
Back to issue, I will try to reproduce what you suggested and feed you with results ASAP.

Comment: @axiopisty even with SecurityManager disabled and with an `AccessController.doPriviliged` call I still have the same access denied exception.

Comment: What happens if you remove the AccessController.doPriviliged and run it without the security manager?

Comment: Same issue if I remove it, still the `Pemission Denied` exception occurs. First I thought the issue was there and even mentioned it in my original post, but removing it lead to same result so I updated my issue description.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with permissions at the level of the os. What happens if you run it without the security manager, without the do privileged, and run the start up service script as root?

Comment: If I run the service as a super user, I will certainly gain read/write acess to almost the whole OS and thus won't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you have a jboss-user created on your system. I'm supposing this because you're using the path `/home/jboss-user/report`.

This means that if you run the command `grep -n "jboss-user" /etc/passwd` you should see something in the output that indicates that 1) there is a jboss-user on the system, and 2) the user home directory for that user is `/home/jboss-user`.

You mentioned in the OP that you're trying to start the service using the command `sudo -u exo service jboss start`.

But this command is not really starting the service with the jboss-user, but rather the exo user. Try this:

```
sudo -u jboss-user service jboss start
```

Also, what is the output of `ls -a /home/jboss-user`? It looks like the file permissions on the `/home/jboss-user/report` directory should allow the operation, but if the permissions on `/home/jboss-user` do not allow the `exo` user to access the `/home/jboss-user/report` directory, that could be the problem.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, but I actually run the service with **jboss-user** as owner as mentioned in the OP (even the command introduced a typo):

>    then tried to make sure that it is run with *jboss-user* as a user